# Why won't my class import in Python?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module

**Edit:**  `__init__.py` files are included, but I'm using Python 3 - I don't think it matters.

**Another edit:** Anything in `config.py` will import with no problem.  If I simply omit `from cache import Cache` then no errors.  Interestingly, no errors occur when importing `Config` in `config.py`

I cannot figure out what's wrong here.  I'm getting an error whenever I try to import a specific class.  Here's what my project layout looks like:

```
app/
    dir1/
        config.py
        cache.py
        manager.py
        __init__.py
    test/
        test.py
        __init__.py
```

**cache.py:**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from manager import Manager, AnotherClass
from config import Config
```

**manager.py**

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
from config import Config
from cache import Cache
```

**test.py**

```
cwd = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, os.pardir)) + '/dir1')
from cache import Cache, AnotherClass
from manager import Manager
test = Cache()
...
```

So when I run test.py I get this:

```
File "/path/to/project/app/dir1/<module>
from cache import Cache

ImportError: cannot import name 'Cache'

from manager import Manager line 5,
```

Even though `config.Config` loads just fine, no errors there, but as soon as I try to import `cache.Cache` it suddenly can't find or import any class in `cache.py`.  All files have the same permissions.  Can someone tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: You dont have `__init__.py` files in modules.

Comment: Related - [What is __init__.py for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for_)

Comment: You should check whether the directory is already in sys.path.  It's just a plain list, and if you keep appending to it, it's going to get very big.

Comment: `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, os.pardir)) + '/dir1'` should be `os.path.abspath(os.path.join(cwd, os.pardir, 'dir1'))` - os.path.join can take an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: @MartinBonner in these cases you shouldn't modify `sys.path` at all.

Comment: init.py is in there.  Actually I'm using Python 3 so I don't think it matters, but I'll modify the question anyway.

Comment: @NilsWerner: Absolutely agree.  My comments were in the general case where you needed to do something like this.  (I should have noted that at the start of the comment.)

Comment: @NilsWerner - I actually didn't want to modify sys.path, but at the time I recall this was the easiest, simple solution.  What would you do instead?

Comment: @DanChrostowski Look at my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the `__init__.py` file in your module

```
app/
    __init__.py
    dir1/
        __init__.py
        config.py
        cache.py
        manager.py
    test/
        test.py
```

and instead of messing with `sys.path` should do a relative import like

```
from .config import Config
from .cache import Cache
```

Python 2 may also need a line

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
```

before those imports.